# How to convert QByteArray to QString?

Tags: java, c++, qt, encoding

Here is HttpServer in JAVA, that sends russian string to Qt application:

```
 public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        //Response from server in Russian
        String response = "Ответ от сервера на русском языке"; //"Response from server in Russian"
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        //os.write(response.getBytes());
       //right now I am trying this code
      os.write(response.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); //and UTF-16
       //also I have tried this
        os.write(Charset.forName("UTF-16").encode(response).array());

        os.close();
    }
```

Application in Qt gets response from server (text in russian)

```
 void MainWindow::Response(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
   // Also I've tried this
   // QString dataString = (QString)reply->readAll();
   // QString dataLine = (QString)reply->readLine();
   // QString str=  QString::fromUtf8(data);
    qDebug() << "data from server: " << data;
     label->setText(str);
}
```

I just want to show normal string in console or in label component, but I have 
empty string or array of bytes or sequence of question marks

"\xCE\xF2\xE2\xE5\xF2 \xEE\xF2 \xF1\xE5\xF0\xE2\xE5\xF0\xE0 \xED\xE0 \xF0\xF3\xF1\xF1\xEA\xEE\xEC \xFF\xE7\xFB\xEA\xE5"

How can I solve this problem with encoding and convert this array to QString and finally see the normal text ?

Comment: See the group of QString::fromUtf* methods. Other than that the question is not unique and was answered here not just once.

Comment: I've tried everything, nothing works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### [getBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes())
>
> ```
> public byte[] getBytes()
> ```
>
> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.
>
> The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the default charset is unspecified. The `CharsetEncoder` class should be used when more control over the encoding process is required.

Using this method to serialize the string is a *terrible* idea; the "platform default encoding" depends from current locale, operating system and whatnot, while you want a well-defined encoding to transmit data between applications.

In facts, I trust you when you say "I've tried everything, nothing works" - that's because your string is encoded in the [windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) encoding, which probably happens to be the default 8-bit encoding of your Windows machine. When you try to decode it on the Qt side - which, from Qt5, always expects UTF-8 by default when decoding 8-bit strings, everything breaks.

---

First of all, on the Java side [encode your string in UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5729828/214671), making sure to specify the response length correctly (you have to provide the number of *bytes* you are writing, not of characters in the source string):

```
String response = "Ответ от сервера на русском языке"; //"Response from server in Russian"
byte[] response_data = response.getBytes("UTF-8");
t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response_data.length());
OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
os.write(response_data);
os.close();
```

Then, on the Qt side, you can build a `QString` from the `QByteArray`, specifying it's in UTF8.

```
QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
QString str = QString::fromUtf8(data);
```

(notice that you may send your string in UTF-16 or UTF-32 as well, but of course the two sides must match; I chose UTF-8 because it's way more common as an "on the wire" format and because it's generally more compact)

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, I understand now,
but there is a little problem  OutputStream os.write() can not accept Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(response) I have tried with Channels but it doesn't work 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/579616/7823223

Comment: "can not accept" has no meaning... what error do you get? Did you do `import java.nio.charset.Charset;`?

Comment: Seems a little odd to convert to and from UTF-8, since both Java and Qt use UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: Of course I imported that library. The method write(int) in the type OutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (ByteBuffer). I've tried to apply method array():
 os.write(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(response).array());
but I get emptry string in Qt client

Comment: [Channels seem to be the way to go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579600/how-to-put-the-content-of-a-bytebuffer-into-an-outputstream), or you can get a byte array [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679298/gets-byte-array-from-a-bytebuffer-in-java). Sorry but I never worked in Java, so my suggestions may be a bit off on that side.

Comment: @MrEricSir: and just think that every integer in network protocols travels in big endian, while virtually every machine is little endian; at least in this case there's a distinct advantage (UTF-8 being generally more compact than UTF-16).

Comment: Oh gosh, there's another overload of the `getBytes` that takes the encoding as a parameter and returns a `byte[]`; it was way simpler than all this `ByteBuffer` mess. :-)

Comment: I have just tried this os.write(response.getBytes("UTF-8"));
but I still get empy string in qt, I am desperate with this :(  So simple task - just send response, with English text everything works well

Comment: Is it failing to encode, to decode or to transmit? If you write out the byte array on the Java side is it sane? What do you get in the `QByteArray` on the Qt side? Also, you'll quickly learn that there's no such a thing as a "simple task" when dealing with text and encodings.

Comment: It is failing to decode in qt, I tried this  os.write(response.getBytes("UTF-16")); (also UTF-8)
and in qt   QString str1 = QString::fromUtf16(reinterpret_cast<const ushort*>(data.constData()), 10); and     QString str2 = QString::fromUtf8(data);  Convertation fromutf16 gives this 
= "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\uFFFF\uFFFF"

Comment: Again, what do you get if you do `qDebug()<<data`, as you did before?

Comment: qDebug() << data;  gives "" -empty

Comment: Well of course if you did `response.getBytes("UTF-16")`... use UTF-8. If it still gives you an empty string, check what you are sending on the java side (dump `response.getBytes("UTF-8")`).

Comment: If I send text in English - everything is alright in qt, I get it, but the same doesn't work with russian text, it is like magic

Comment: Please update the post with the current code, I can't understand what you are testing now.

Comment: Ok, now, I see that in the example above you call `Charset.forName("UTF-16").encode(response).array()` - don't do that, `.array()` is not guaranteed to return anything meaningful, and UTF-16 is not what we are after. Use the straight `os.write(response.getBytes("UTF-8"))`. What do you get with `qDebug()<<data;` on the other side?

Comment: QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
data.size() = 0, it is really weird, because if I send  text in English - it works and data is NOT null
I tested with this java code: os.write(response.getBytes("UTF-8"))

Comment: Aaaah there it is; the response length is wrong; you are writing in the number of UTF-16 *characters*, but you are sending UTF-8 bytes. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you! big thank you! спасибо большое:) I got this message in qt client, and I even displayed it in console and in label with correct encoding, everything works perfectly now!

Comment: You're welcome; I'm sorry it took so long, but I didn't notice that you were passing the string size when writing the headers (which is actually quite obvious thinking about how the HTTP response has to be composed). Glad it helped. :-)